# Angular directive $compile vs event $compile

Tags: angularjs

Why does the $compile fail during a button click?  Works fine in the directive. I also tried the $compile in an $apply function block, but that didn't work either.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rB5zteYTZ2L1WB5RzlHg

index.html

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  {{message}}
  <div my-content>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
var app=angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', 
    function($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {
      $scope.label="| LABEL 1";
      $scope.elem={};
      $scope.message="";
      $scope.doSomething = function(){
        $scope.message = "should read TITLE 2 | LABEL 2 ---->";
        $scope.label="| LABLE 2";

        $scope.activeTemplate = $scope.template2;

        var linkFn = $compile($scope.activeTemplate);
        var content = linkFn($scope);
        $scope.elem.replaceWith(content);

      };
      $scope.activeTemplate="<button ng-click='doSomething()'>TITLE 1 {{label}}</button>";
      $scope.template2="<button ng-click='doSomething()'>TITLE 2 {{label}}</button>";
    }
  );

app.directive("myContent", function($compile){
return {
    link: function(scope, element){
        var template =scope.activeTemplate;
        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        element.replaceWith(content);
        scope.elem=element;
    }
```

};
});

The problem, or at least error happens at:
    $scope.elem.replaceWith(content);

in the button event.  $scope.elem seems valid, so I'm not really sure what it is

error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:151:140
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:7:290)
    at r.replaceWith (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:151:81)
    at Object.S.(anonymous function) [as replaceWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:154:73)
    at k.$scope.doSomething (http://run.plnkr.co/FY9K9EgxTDQoYQgJ/main.js:15:25)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:177:68
    at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:194:174)
    at k.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:68)
    at k.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:346)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:194:226) angular.js:10072

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is but it looks like you are trying $compile and $apply to achieve what an isolate scope in your directive would handle much cleaner.

Comment: I would just like to be able to change my template with a button click. The template will be dynamically created, I need a way to compile that dynamically created template, but the directive only gets called on the first page load from what I can tell. I'm not sure how an isolate scope would help with that?